# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toString

Tags: java

I made a java program with gradle. I have jdk 15 on my computer but in the gradle file I put :

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

so it can run with java 8.

I send the jar file to someone that uses java 8 and it works perfectly fine. On my computer, it works perfectly fine with java 8 and java 15.

I send the jar file to another person and he gets the following error :

```
[ERROR)Exceptioninthread'Thread-7"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toString(Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String;
[ERROR)    at fr.bloomenetwork.fatestaynight.packager.Utils.docxToKsFile(Utils.java:84)
[ERROR)    at fr.bloomenetwork.fatestaynight.packager.FetchingThread.run(FetchingThread.java:197)
[ERROR)    at java.lang.Thread.run(UnknownSource)
```

I don't undestand why he gets this error if it works fine for me and the other person.

Here is the code that raise the error :

```java
public static void docxToKsFile(InputStream is, String filename) throws IOException {
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayOutputStream fos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipEntry ze = null;
        String xmlContent = null;
        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            if (ze.getName().equals("word/document.xml")) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
                int len;
                while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);          
                }
                xmlContent =  new String(fos.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); //Here is line 84
                fos.close();
                break;
            }
        }
        fos.close();
        String txtContent = xmlContent.replaceAll("</w:p>", "\n"); 
        txtContent = txtContent.replaceAll("<[^>]*/?>", "");
        txtContent = txtContent.replaceAll("&amp;", "&");
        txtContent = txtContent.replaceAll("&quot;", "\"");
        java.nio.file.Files.write(Paths.get(filename), txtContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
```

Comment: May be stupid question. Did this another person checked whether he is also using java 8 or higher version ?

Comment: Make sure that all of you are actually running it on Java 8. According to [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toString(java.nio.charset.Charset)) `ByteArrayOutputStream#toString(java.nio.charset.Charset)` method was introduced in Java 10.

Comment: He is running java 15. That's what is strange.

Comment: Your comment makes your question unclear. Did you try to run it on java 15, java 8 or both? Does your friend run it on Java 8 or Java 15?

Comment: I tried running it on both and it doesn't work with java 8. My friend runs java 15 and it doesn't work.

Comment: After some investigation, I found that he has java 15 and when he runs `java -version` he gets jdk 15. The problem was that jre 8 ran the jar file when he uses the file explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [javadoc of `ByteArrayOutputStream`'s `toString(Charset)` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toString(java.nio.charset.Charset)), it was added in Java10, and is thus not available on JDK8.

> ```
> sourceCompatibility = 1.8
> targetCompatibility = 1.8
> ```
>
> so it can run with java 8.

That's not what that means. That merely means the source files are compiled using the JDK8 idea of java-the-language, and that the produces class files are in JDK8 format. It does nothing to guarantee that you are only using the JDK8 idea of the core libraries. Those gradle options are the gradle equivalent of `javac`'s `--source` resp. `--target` options.

Those are the wrong options.

With javac, there is now a `--release` option (introduced in.. I think JDK8?) which covers both source and target compatibility, and even warns about trying to use core library calls that weren't in the stated release. Let's try it, with JDK14 which I happen to have installed on my machine (but should work with JDK11 too):

```
echo "class Test {{ new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream().toString(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8); }}" > Test.java
javac -version
> javac 14.0.1
javac --release 8 Test.java
> Test.java:1: error: no suitable method found for toString(Charset)
javac --release 11 Test.java
> [no message; it compiles fine]
```

As per the [current gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html), `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` are ***deprecated*** and should no longer be used. Use `options.release = 8` instead, which is the gradle variant of the `--release` option. Yay!

NB: `.toString("UTF-8")` is ugly, but does work; it was introduced before java8.

NB2:

> On my computer, it works perfectly fine with java 8 and java 15.

Nope. You weren't running it on java8 on your machine. If you had, the app would have failed with the same error. Must have accidentally used the wrong one :P

Comment: You are right. I didn't see that this method was only available with jdk 10. But what is strange here is that the person who is able to run the jar file is using java 8 and the person who is not able to is running java 15.

Comment: Finally you were perfectly right. He was using java 8 without knowing it because he has both versions. Thanks for the advice in gradle.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
xmlContent =  new String(fos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thank you it works with both jdk 8 and 15.